# Where does go job take the environment variables from?

Tags: docker, pipeline, continuous-delivery, go-cd, go-agent

When I execute the printenv command on the go-agent

```
go@05f749b73185:/tmp$ printenv
HOSTNAME=05f749b73185
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=go
LS_COLORS=
MAVEN_VERSION=3.3.9
MAIL=/var/mail/go
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven
PWD=/tmp
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HOME=/var/go
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=go
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

But when I execute the printenv command from inside a job i get this result

```
06:57:26.482 [go] Start to execute task: <exec command="printenv" />.
06:57:26.493 GO_SERVER_URL=https://go-server:8154/go/
06:57:26.493 JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
06:57:26.494 SHLVL=2
06:57:26.494 MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven
06:57:26.495 LOG_DIR=/var/log/go-agent
06:57:26.495 GO_TRIGGER_USER=anonymous
06:57:26.495 GO_SERVER=go-server
06:57:26.496 GO_PIPELINE_LABEL=8
06:57:26.496 GO_STAGE_NAME=build
06:57:26.497 HOSTNAME=05f749b73185
06:57:26.497 PWD=/var/lib/go-agent
06:57:26.498 GO_STAGE_COUNTER=1
06:57:26.498 AGENT_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/go-agent
06:57:26.499 GO_JOB_NAME=Compile
06:57:26.499 MAVEN_VERSION=3.3.9
06:57:26.499 OLDPWD=/etc/service/go-agent
06:57:26.500 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
06:57:26.500 AGENT_STARTUP_ARGS=-Dcruise.console.publish.interval=10 -Xms128m -Xmx256m    -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
06:57:26.501 GO_FROM_REVISION=b6f8f0f3bedabe1cc0ffa1334c290f32da723cde
06:57:26.501 PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
06:57:26.501 GO_TO_REVISION=b6f8f0f3bedabe1cc0ffa1334c290f32da723cde
06:57:26.502 USER=go
06:57:26.502 GO_SERVER_PORT=8153
06:57:26.502 GO_PIPELINE_NAME=DropwizardSeed
06:57:26.503 HOME=/var/go
06:57:26.503 UID=103
06:57:26.503 GO_ENVIRONMENT_NAME=local
06:57:26.506 INITRD=no
06:57:26.507 GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER=8
06:57:26.508 GO_REVISION=b6f8f0f3bedabe1cc0ffa1334c290f32da723cde
06:57:26.509 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

If you look at the JAVA_HOME environment variable it's different between the job call and the call directly when you're logged in the machine.
This can be solved by setting the environment variable in the pipeline, but how can I configure my go-server and go-agents so I don't have to do this? What if I want to use another JDK as default?

Where does that JAVA_HOME environment variable come from?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked `/etc/default/<agent-name>`
In this file you can define the default values for an agent and you can also define environment variables using `export` command.